# Seismic Design Changes between ASCE and UBC Code?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, building-design, seismic

what is the difference between the seismic design between ASCE and UBC code?
from load combinations to loads applied to the history between the sudden shift or change in the code. and which one of the codes does it result in over-reinforcement  (or overdesign) i mean what code for example will give column dimensions >> than the other one ...

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This is a massive topic. I would highly suggest reading the commentary of the ASCE 7 code for more information. I find it unlikely this post allowed to stay open.

Comment: Hi ShadowMan thank you for your reply, sorry for the vague topic i am really interested in the history of the two codes meaning what event or seismic catastrophe has triggered the transition from the UBC to IBC code. And Was there any issue in particular (in seismic and Wind) from the designer point of view that showed that the UBC is not realistic or giving bad results ? Thank you in Advance and sorry again for the vague post.

Comment: My best suggestion for you is to read all of the commentary in the asce 7 including expanded seismic. And perhaps some of the commentary in the IBC. You might do this for each successive version since the UBC. Each earthquake we learn more about the nature of our design method and the flaws.